# if i import a model from blender into unreal engine 4 will the lamps come with it?

Tags: modeling, export, import, lighting

so I'm trying to make 3d models for a game I'm making in unreal engine 4. and I've been doing research on how they import using the fbx files it and I know the materials will import with it, but i cant find anything to tell me wether or not lamps will come with it... i don't really care either way, but i need to know if it will

Comment: Why not try it and find out? But my guess is no, they won't, because UE uses its own lighting system.

Comment: yeah, i guess i'll eventually find out, im just wondering wether or not to do all the extra work